# Resize Columns To Fit Lengt - JavaScript - Math

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, grid

Given a width of a grid and the target size of a column, I want to calculate a new size for the column, that is as close to the target size as possible.

**For example:**

```
gridSize: 10, targetSize: 9, newSize: 10
gridSize: 100, targetSize: 51, newSize: 50
gridSize: 20, targetSize: 6, newSize: 6.66667
...
```

**Visualization:**

[image]

If the target size is larger than the grid, it should default to the grid width.

Here is some code:

```
function calculateSize(gridWidth, targetSize){
         
  var newSize = 0;

  if(targetSize > gridWidth){

   // The target size is larger than the grid, default to maximum width

   newSize = gridWidth;

  }
  else{

    // Calculate new size, that is as close to the target size as possible

    var count = gridWidth / targetSize;
    var difference = Math.round(gridWidth / count) - gridWidth / count;
    
    // I don't know how to reach the desired result with these two values, maybe my approach is wrong

  }

  return newSize;

}
```

I am sure this is really easy, but Math is not my strong suit. Does anyone know how to calculate this? Thanks!

Comment: no visual example ? I'm  a bit confusing on this, Am I the only one ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I can visualize it. Let me create a graphic and add it to the question.

Comment: ` // I don't know how to continue at this point` what do you not know what to do there? What are you missing that needs to be done?

Comment: I came so far as to calculate the difference, from there I don't know how to divide it up equally to reach the desired result. My attempts were so far off that I thought it would be misleading to include them.

Comment: why simply  not `count = Math.floor( gridWidth / targetSize )`  ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I wanted to get the difference from the rounded number to the target, in order to divide it up in the next step. However, I feel that this was totally the wrong approach, which is why I omitted it. Also, Math.floor would always round down, I want to round up too if necessary, (if rounding up is closer to the target value than rounding down).

Comment: column size is assumed to always be an integer value?

Comment: For the input/target yes, but the new size can also be a float of course.

Comment: if the value is float then the previous calculation is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

possibilities

```js
function calculateSize(gridWidth, targetSize)
  {
  let inOut = { in:{}, out:{} }
  inOut.in.count     = Math.floor( gridWidth / targetSize )
  inOut.in.size      = Math.floor(gridWidth / inOut.in.count)
  inOut.in.sizefloat = gridWidth / inOut.in.count
  inOut.in.delta     = gridWidth - (inOut.in.count * inOut.in.size )

  inOut.out.size  = inOut.in.size +1
  inOut.out.count = inOut.in.count
  inOut.out.delta = (inOut.out.count * inOut.out.size ) - gridWidth

  inOut.best = (inOut.out.delta < inOut.in.delta) 
              ? `${inOut.out.count} columns of ${inOut.out.size} pixels (out)` 
              : `${inOut.in.count} columns  of ${inOut.in.size} pixels (in)` 

  return inOut
  }


console.log(  calculateSize(20,6)  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```